# what element do I bind using jquery to close a selector?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a custom-created (no plugins used, except for jquery) selector like this:

### [image: selector]

The **list** of items is an element called **.selectorList**.

I open it like this:

```
$("#selectorReplacement").click(function(){
   $("#.selectorList").stop(true,true).slideToggle(0);
});
```

It's all OK and functions great, the problem comes as I want to close it. I can close it by clicking on **#selectorReplacement**, as that is bound to do so, but I also would like this element to close when I click **whenever else on the site**, just as the original `<select>` works.

Where do I bind this? If it do it like this:

```
$("body").click(function(){
   $(".selectorList").slideUp(0);
});
```

Then I cannot even open it, because **body** spans all the site, so even when I click on the element opener, it automatically closes because of this bind.

I would need something like, $("everything except #selectorReplacement")

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return `false` from

```
$("#selectorReplacement").click(function(){
   $("#.selectorList").stop(true,true).slideToggle(0);
   return false;
});
```

Comment: this actually works! could you explain **why** or **how** it works?

Answer (score 1):

Modify the open code to do this:

```
$("#selectorReplacement").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   $("#.selectorList").stop(true,true).slideToggle(0);
});
```

This should stop the event bubbling up to the body when you click it the selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$('html').click(function(e){
    if($(e.target).closest('#selectorReplacement').length == 0) {
        $('#selectorReplacement').slideUp(0);
    }
});
```

Or you can set up a timeout function which closing your box after a minimum time.

Answer (score 0):

For my custom context menu i bound a click event to the document.

```
$(document).bind('click', function() {});
```